# Getting model properties list in MongoEngine

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

How can I get a list of properties defined for a given model (document) in MongoEngine?

In Django, I can do ModelName._meta.fields to get that list, however the similar API doesn't exist for MongoEngine.

I'm quite convinced there has to be such a list/method, since they need to create the document from that definition strictly.. just trying to find where..

For example, I have this document defined:

```
import mongoengine as me

class ModelName(me.Document):
    name = me.StringField()
    is_active = me.BooleanField()
```

I want to find the general method to get the properties (nam, is_active) in a Python list.

Comment: Apparently you can use the `_fields` property: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8587151/1267329

Comment: @SimeonVisser That's a dup.